# Gem for sorting and searching

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am using rails version 3.2.6. I have to use the gem for sorting and searching for the index pages in my application. I know about `jquery-datatables-rails` gem. I just want to know if there is some other gem for sorting and searching that is supported in rails 3.2.6. I had also searched for datagrid gem but did not get the proper ducumentation for that and if it(datagrid) is supported in rails 3.2.6.

Answer (score 0):

Active Scaffold (https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold) is probably over top, or? Its my most-used-gem. Of course it has sorting and searching build in, configurable and fast. Check it out, following the getting started guide in the wiki you should have an app up and running in 10 minutes.

Comment: Thank you so much  for your help. Can you please send me some useful links so that I can understand the basic concept of this gem and how to use it?

Comment: The github page referenced above has a nice Wiki. Go there and then then to "Getting Started". Or, as a shortcut, follow: https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: And the "Howto approach.." section (https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/wiki/How-to-Approach-Active-Scaffold-%28Use-Cases-and-Benefits%29) has a nice introductory chapter.